# I want to export from Access to Excel a Table I created in Access without Access asking me if I want to overwrite the existing file

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible without VBA?  I can send the file the first time with no problem.  I can manually go in and delete the file then run Access - no problems.  I want Access to run and then overwrite the existing Excel file without asking me if I want it overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think is possible without VBA.

Delete the file before exporting.

```
Dim strFile As String
strFile = "your filepath here"
If Dir(strFile) <> "" Then Kill(strFile)
'export code here
```

Comment: Do I put this in a module? Public Sub Dim strFile As String
strFile = "your filepath here"
If Dir(strFile) <> "" Then Kill(strFile)
'export code here End Sub

Comment: Yes, it goes in a VBA module. Can be a button Click event behind form. How do you want to specific filepath?

Comment: Public Sub DeleteFile()
Dim strFile As String
strFile = "Legacy-DC1\CompanyData\Departments\Finance\Misc. MHP\AAPayroll\PR Import\PayRollJE.xlsx"
If Dir(strFile) <> "" Then Kill (strFile)
End Sub

Comment: Nope.  I copied the path from Explorer.

Comment: Can this just be RunCode in a Macro?

Comment: Edit your question with attempted code. Your filepath is incomplete. There is no drive designation. If Legacy-DC1 is server name it must be preceded with two backslashes. That is UNC pathing. I don't use macros. Even so, still need valid VBA procedure because RunCode calls VBA.